# Avoid that labels are overwritten in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a set of Chicago districts and a set points but when I plotted the points the district  legend gets overwritten. I want to preserve the two labels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,  figsize = (10,17))

# using the condition
axis = geochicago[condition].plot(ax=ax, 
                                  column='pri_neigh', 
                                  cmap='Greys', 
                                  linewidth=2, 
                                  edgecolor='red',
                                  legend=True)
# axis.annotate('Source: https://www.chicago.gov/city/en/depts/dgs/supp_info/gis.html', xy=(-.1, -.1))

subsetGeotable.plot(ax=axis, 
                    column='id',
                    edgecolor='white', 
                    cmap='tab20b', 
                    categorical=True, 
                    legend=True,
                    linewidth=0.2)
_ = axis.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This is the image after to plot the district.

[image]

This is the plot after plotting the points information, the original label gets overwritten.

[image]

Comment: You can probably [specify the legend location](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes) somehow

Comment: As BERA says, It is a a [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) proglem, not a geospatial problem